# Azure AD Application Register - How to provide 'Application Type' when registering an application using powershell or graph API?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Just like in portal, we can provide application type (i.e. WebApp/API or Native). Where can we provide this when using powershell cmds or graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the command below to create a `Web app / API` type Azure AD application.

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "<YourAppName>"  -ReplyUrls "<ReplyUrls>"
```

If you want to create a `Native` type application, you could set`-PublicClient` property to `$true`, the default value of it is `false`, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/New-AzureADApplication?view=azureadps-2.0).

This is the command to create a `Native` application, it works fine on my side.

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "joytestapp3"  -ReplyUrls "<ReplyUrls>" -PublicClient $true
```

Check it in the portal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The application type is a single boolean property on the app: `publicClient`.

If publicClient is true, the app is Native.
If it is false, then the app is Web app/API.

[Azure AD Graph API entity reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity)

In the MS Graph API beta endpoint I believe the equivalent property is `allowPublicClient`:

[Microsoft Graph API entity reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application)

MS Graph API application management is still beta and not recommended for production use.
The entity model there has had heavy changes and might continue to do so.
It is recommended to use Azure AD Graph API for application management.

With Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets, you can use `-PublicClient $true` and `-PublicClient $false`.